# How to read file generated dynamically in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I have Spring boot application, in which I am generating file dynamically and want flyway plugin to read file at the same time.

I am able to generate file but not able to find the file at the same run by flyway plugin. If I refresh app it shows that file and able to read at next run.

I want that generates and at same time able to read.

```
 spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=
```

tried this but it restarts application and write into same file only. because of that records are duplicated and also it not refresh resource dir so not able to read.

I tried many other ways but couldn't work for me. Is there any solution.

Comment: We are creating and reading file at same time without any issue and without any special configuration. Can you share some code snippet